# What is the modern C++ way of handling multi-channel data using span?

Tags: c++, audio, c++20, std-span

I have learned that since `std::<span>`'s introduction in C++20, we no longer need to use the traditional `void read(T* input, int numSamples)` API and can instead pass in a span that encompasses both the content and size in a non-owning way. My question is, if we are handling multi-channel data, what should this become? Would it be a `std::span<std::span<T>>`? That doesn't seem to make sense since the spanned elements should be contiguous.

Previously the file IO API I saw either used `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` directly, or used raw pointers like `T** channels`, which didn't seem to be as general and modern as it can be.

Comment: Thats why we have `mdspan` now.

Comment: Woah I really should learn more about c++ 23! I'll look into it! Thanks :)

Comment: When you say “channels” do you mean something like iovec?